# how to graph data which is splitted into two lines

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two lines of data

```
A B C D E F G
5 9 3 4 8 3 1

H I J K L M N
6 8 9 3 1 6 2
```

I want to graph them like graphing this

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N
5 9 3 4 8 3 1 6 8 9 3 1 6 2
```

I meant, to make it look like this (I made up the numbers so it's just an example)

[image]

Basically they are the same dataset but it's too long just writing them as one line so I want to split it into two but doing this messed up the whole graph. Is there any way to do it, or can I combine separate 2 graphs like just putting one right after another?

Comment: Why don't you write them as two vertical columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use Power Query:

1. Select Range 1 and go to **Data**- **From Sheet**- open **Power Query Editor** and select the Range in Table 1- go to **Transform** tab- select **Unpivot Columns**- select **Home** tab and **Close & Load to...**- Select **Pivot Chart**:

[image]

2. Select Range 2 and go to **Data**- **From Sheet**- open **Power Query Editor** and select the Range in Table 2- go to **Transform** tab- select **Unpivot Columns**- go to **Home** tab under **Combine** select **Append Queries**- **Table to append** select **Table 2** and click **OK**- **Close and Load**- Create the Pivot Chart:

[image]